# Cannot change my Home directory

Tags: path, cygwin

My path home on cygwin is this:
/cygdrive/c/Users/JulioKayak.DESKTOP-UM5MV5B

But when I open it and type pwd, I'm here: /cygdrive/c/Users/JulioKayak

Comment: `/cygdrive/c/Users/JulioKayak` seems fine. `JulioKayak.DESKTOP-UM5MV5B` seems an unusual name for a user. What is the output of `whoami` and `echo $HOME` ?

Comment: when I use whoami it puts JulioKayak, but dunno how I use the JulioKayak.DESKTOP-UM5MV5B folder. The JulioKayak user folder dont have access to desktop as the other have

Answer (score 0):

The recommended set for Cygwin home directory is

```
/home/$USERNAME
```

this to avoid using the Windows home directory as cygwin one.
To change it or reset to the default please follow instruction at

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-passwdinfo

Specifically look at content of files:

```
/etc/passwd 
/etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Usually none of the two are needed.